# No index provider spatial found : Embedded Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-spatial

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
                <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

                <groupId>com.erranda</groupId>
                <artifactId>prototype</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>

                <parent>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
                </parent>
                <properties>
                    <wicket.version>6.18.0</wicket.version>
                </properties>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wicket-spring</artifactId>
                        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wicket-extensions</artifactId>
                        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wicket-auth-roles</artifactId>
                        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.wicketstuff</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wicketstuff-htmlcompressor</artifactId>
                        <version>6.18.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                        <version>3.3.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
                        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
                        <version>2.6</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <!-- Javax Mail -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <!-- Geocoding -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.google.code.geocoder-java</groupId>
                        <artifactId>geocoder-java</artifactId>
                        <version>0.16</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-rest</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.vaynberg.wicket.select2</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wicket-select2</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <!-- Commons -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>neo4j-spatial</artifactId>
                        <version>0.9</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <build>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <!-- Copy wicket HTML and other resource files from the java directory -->
                            <filtering>false</filtering>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.html</include>
                                <include>**/*.js</include>
                                <include>**/*.png</include>
                                <include>**/*.css</include>
                                <include>**/*.jpg</include>
                                <include>**/*.properties</include>
                            </includes>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </resource>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>3.1</version>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </build>

                <repositories>
                    <repository>
                        <id>spring-releases</id>
                        <name>Spring Releases</name>
                        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
                    </repository>
                    <repository>
                        <id>neo4j-public-release-repository</id>
                        <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/releases</url>
                        <snapshots>
                            <enabled>false</enabled>
                        </snapshots>
                    </repository>
                </repositories>

                <pluginRepositories>
                    <pluginRepository>
                        <id>spring-releases</id>
                        <name>Spring Releases</name>
                        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
                    </pluginRepository>
                </pluginRepositories>

            </project>
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/3.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/programming-model.html#reference_spatial

The link appears to be misleading because on adding the dependency to my pom file I still get the subject error. This however is not the case when I run it against a server with a spatial plugin.

Comment: Can you provide an output of mvn dependency:tree ?

Comment: Too large to paste here. I use spring-boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this repository in your maven pom

```
            <repository>
                        <id>neo4j-contrib-releases</id>
                        <url>https://raw.github.com/neo4j-contrib/m2/master/releases</url>
                        <releases>
                            <enabled>true</enabled>
                        </releases>
                        <snapshots>
                            <enabled>false</enabled>
                        </snapshots>
                    </repository>
                    <repository>
                        <id>neo4j-contrib-snapshots</id>
                        <url>https://raw.github.com/neo4j-contrib/m2/master/snapshots</url>
                        <releases>
                            <enabled>false</enabled>
                        </releases>
                        <snapshots>
                            <enabled>true</enabled>
                        </snapshots>
                    </repository>
```

with the dependency

```
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>neo4j-spatial</artifactId>
                    <version>0.13-neo4j-2.1.2</version>
                </dependency>
```